# Doing "curl -u" with Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm working with a service that requires me to call it via:

```
curl -u username:password -X POST "http://www.theirurl.com"
```

I'd like to use Guzzle rather than do a raw CURL, however.  Is there a way to have Guzzle pass the `-u` parameter?  I tried User-Agent, but that's not correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a user agent, that's HTTP Basic Authentication.

```
$client->post('http://www.theirurl.com/', ['auth' => ['username', 'password']]);
```

http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html?highlight=auth#auth

Comment: This seems not working with Guzzle 5+ or Guzzle 6+... Any idea?

Comment: @Aerendir Doesn't appear to have changed in later versions. http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html?highlight=auth#auth

Comment: I'm not yet practical about those auth methods: is this oAuth? Is this valid to connect, for example, to WooCommerce API that requires oAuth? http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication

Comment: @Aerendir No, this is not oAuth.  Guzzle has an oAuth subscriber at https://github.com/guzzle/oauth-subscriber.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm trying to make it work, but it seems it doesn't. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456066/how-to-use-oauth-with-guzzle-5