# How to update woocommerce product via api with Symfony and Guzzle

Tags: php, symfony, woocommerce, guzzle, woocommerce-rest-api

Question: How to update the price of a woocommerce product via API using Guzzle and guzzle/oauth-subscriber

I've used [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456066/how-to-use-oauth-with-guzzle-5-or-better-with-guzzle-6) as my reference to get oauth1 working for requesting data, which works well. Just haven't been able to workout out to send post variables.

Most tutorials and the guzzle docs use the `$client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org', [ 'query' => ['foo' => 'bar'] ]);` but that isn't working either:

```
        $response = $client->request('POST', $endpoint, [
            'auth' => 'oauth',
            'form_params' => [
                'price' => '21'
            ]
        ]);
```

This is my current code, with the get `$client->get()` commented out what successfully returns a product.

```
        $endpoint = 'products/12';

        $handler = new \GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler();
        $stack = \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create($handler);

        $middleware = new \GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1([
            'consumer_key'    => $this->consumer_key,
            'consumer_secret' => $this->consumer_secret,
            'token_secret'    => '',
            'token'           => '',
            'request_method' => Oauth1::REQUEST_METHOD_QUERY,
            'signature_method' => Oauth1::SIGNATURE_METHOD_HMAC
        ]);
        $stack->push($middleware);

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => $this->url . $this->api,
            'handler' => $stack
        ]);

        $response = $client->post( $endpoint, [ 'auth' => 'oauth' ], ['price' => '21'] );

        var_dump($response);

        //$response = $client->get( $endpoint, [ 'auth' => 'oauth' ] );
        //return array(
        //  'status' => $response->getStatusCode(),
        //  'header' => $response->getHeaderLine('content-type'),
        //  'body' => json_decode($response->getBody())
        //);
```

Comment: You are sending a `POST` request, you should be sending a `PUT` request. `POST` means "create", `PUT` means "update".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were three issues with my code:

1. Using POST to update, not PUT. As stated POST is to create, not update.
2. Reading [Woocommerce docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties) I found that 'price' is read only, so no combination of parameters I was trying were going to work. `regular_price` is the correct parameter to use here.
3. None of the options I was passing to `$client->` were working, it needs to be a query string. Which I appended to the `$endpoint` variable.

```
$endpoint .= "?stock_quantity=456";
$response = $client->put( $endpoint, [ 'auth' => 'oauth' ] );
```